# Tools for tracking clicks

Tags: click-tracking

Are there any tools availible for tracking users clicks on a website, both internal and external? Preferably one that is free and can track a series of clicks from a user (Example, user clicked 'blog' then 'archives' then a particular article)

Comment: Following this, I'm also looking for one that can just go by server side logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally use https://www.crazyegg.com/ they have a great service. For funneling you can use http://www.kissmetrics.com/ but it has a pricey tag on their service.

Not too sure about internal trackers.

Answer (score 2):

Some server side tools:

- [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)
- [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/)
- [Wusage](http://www.boutell.com/wusage/) (used to be free but it looks like they've changed their model)

A key difference between server side analysis and javascript based analysis is that the js versions will fire a request when a user reloads a page in the browser cache. The server side versions will report only what comes to the server. Neither is inherently "better" - just different. Wikipedia's article on [web analytics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_analytics) discusses this further

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for free [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is your best bet.  It not only gives you a what links where clicked on by name, but it also gives you what links were click on the page using a simple heat map.  I say simple because it won't tell you where on the link that the user clicked on each page, just what % of the clicks on each link on a page.  It doesn't matter if the clicks are inside or out I believe.

If one you want something more complex, then you will need Crazy Egg or Kiss Metrics as Thorn007 stated.

Comment: If only Google wasn't so useless for me. A substantial number of my visitors use noscript. I keep waiting for a start up focused on server side stat processing, so I can go work there :)

Comment: @Tim:  Is it really possible to do server side stat processing?  Javascript is the only way to get a ton of the stats out there.  Any ideas?

Comment: @RandomBen - Sure, the web server records every request, its just a matter of filtering out what you actually want to see.

Comment: @Tim How should you track external links with your server logs? (Without making an url redirector of course)

Comment: @neo - that's just it, you can't track external links without using a redirector. But, with tabbed browsing, you can't even be sure that someone actually _left_ your site to begin with, aside from the lack of activity while they were in another tab. I'm mostly just interested in what people do while active.

Comment: @Tim: How do you know that a substantial number of your visitors use noscript.
Maybe you are just mistaking bots who don't have JavaScript enabled for real visitors?

Comment: @Christian - No, I'm able to cross reference it with IP's that leave comments and otherwise participate. And, users quickly alert me when I implement something new and spiffy without considering graceful fallback.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend open source (PHP - based on Zend Framework) web analytics [Piwik](http://piwik.org/). It is now at version 0.8 and recently get server side tracking API so you can still track those who use noscript or old mobile phones. It's also plugin based so you can explore the [list of available 3rd party plugins](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/query?group=status&milestone=Third+Party+Piwik+Plugins) or build your own. It does click tracking but may not present it easily enough for you, so maybe you do need to write your own plugin for this (don't forget to share it though ;)

If you don't mind spending some money then I recommend [getclicky](http://getclicky.com/)